# MySQL - How to update two tables with one query where table 2 value is true?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Okay, I am trying to update two tables without using PHP and querying a loop.

Table one: users

Table two: traits

BOTH tables have a matching row "ID" (so ID 1 in "users" is also ID 1 in "traits").

TABLE 1 has two rows that need updating: "HP" and "EXP".
TABLE 2 has one row: "STUFF".

I need a simple query to update HP and EXP ONLY if STUFF = 0.

So something like:

```
UPDATE users,traits 
SET 
    traits.hp = 3,
    traits.exp = 10 
WHERE 
    traits.hp < traits.maxhp 
AND users.stuff = 0;
```

This query seems to work, but it is very slow. Is there a better way?

Thank you!

-Josh

Comment: I found the answer myself.

    UPDATE trait t SET t.hp=3, t.exp=10 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT stuff FROM users u ON t.userid=u.userid WHERE u.stuff=0) AND t.hp < t.maxhp;

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the table size, I would recommend creating a couple indexes on those table columns (traits.hp, traints.maxhp and users.stuff) to help keep the query quick.

Also, make sure that your traits.hp and traits.maxhp are set as some sort of numerical (eg. INT) type, otherwise the server will need to try and convert it on-the-fly, which could slow things down as well.

Comment: They are all INT(11).

Comment: I have indexes on all of them, still takes 30 seconds to run. :(

Comment: Any speed increase if you change `UPDATE users,traits` TO `UPDATE traits` (since you aren't actually updating the user table.

Also, do you get the same speed if run directly on the database instead of through PHP?

Comment: I was running it directly from the database. I can't UPDATE only traits since I am calling users from the query. :(

Comment: Are you on a shared host or vps/dedicated? (Can you tweak mysql settings)

If you have access to phpMyAdmin, try to use the MySQL Query Profiler to determine where the issue may be. (after running the query, check the box "Profiling" in the blue bar below the query box (right hand side)

Comment: I am using phpMyAdmin on my VPS. I don't have a profiling box that I can find.